# (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443 on debian 10

Tags: nginx, apache2, nginx-reverse-proxy, nextcloud

I want to install nexcloud with apache2

the problem that I encountered a server with its HTTPS port `80` already taken by another software because i have `nginx` use the port `80`(also the application use port `443` fo ssl) , so i have changed the port of `apache from 80 to 86` by going `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and changing the Listen line there to something like Listen `86`.
and i had go to to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and change the first line to `VirtualHost *: 86.`

then i Restart Apache2 but there was a new error say:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
```

---> `then i have changed 443 ----->7443 on ports.conf and on default-ssl.conf`
and i have again restart apache2 --> there was no error
but when i go to access to the link from my browser i get :

The page isn’t redirecting properly

ps when i type `sudo systemctl status apache2`

the response was:

```
 apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; **disabled**; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-12-13 11:50:56 UTC; 2min 17s ago
```

ANy help please

Comment: what did you type as url in the browser? Perhaps you forgot :86 at the end?